# How to export Editor logs from instruments

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, instruments

I am running a test script in the instruments and wanted to export the Editor log messages. Is there any way I can export them into file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to export the logged messages in the Console to a file from Instruments. You should be able to copy and paste the message text to a text file.

Comment: We can do copy paste but it works on line by line basis. There is no way to multi-select and then perform copy paste operation.

Comment: I was able to select everything in Instruments' Console, copy it, and paste it into a text file. It shouldn't be any different than selecting text in any other Mac application.

Comment: Did u try on Editor log messages? There is no way to multi select them. Command+A, Selection by mouse drag - nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by Editor log messages? The Console is the only view I know of that has log messages. If you want to export the results of an instrument to a file, choose Instrument > Export Track.